# PHP Code don't show anything after the data input

Tags: php, html

I´ve tried a lot of times running the following Code, but, even 
working well, always leaves the same error ( error message 
appears at the same time I open the PHP Code ) =

```
" 
Notice: Undefined index: enviar in 
C:\wamp\www\290.php on  line 2 "
```

( The only thing that I've tried was " try to justify the polemic code 
line 2 " - see line 3 - changing the 2nd line and introduce the 
Code of the 3rd line and all I´ve got is make dissapear the error 
message, but  .... ¡ the code accepts the data input but don't 
show anything in the screen ! )
Here's the Code ( some HTML lines ) - File name = " get.php " -

```
<?php
if ($_GET['enviar']) {
#  if (isset($_GET['enviar']) && $_GET['enviar'] == '1') { 
    echo $_GET['nombre'];
} else {
    ?>
    <form action='get.php' method='get'>
        <p>
            Escribe tu nombre:  <input name='nombre'  type='text'  />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input name='enviar'  value='Enviar datos'  type='submit'  />´
        </p>
    </form>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: what's the url of page ?

Comment: Print the content of GET array.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please fix the [formatting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) in your question. Paste the code, select it, press Ctrl+K (or the `{}` button in the editing toolbar).

Answer (score 1):

From your code:

```
<input name='enviar'  value='Enviar datos'  type='submit'  />
```

Means that in PHP after a `submit`, `$_GET['enviar']` == `"Enviar datos"`

The error you are getting is because before you submit, `$_GET` doesn't have an indices, so you get the notice of an undefined index.  Because it's a submit button, you only have to check to see if the value is set, not verify what it's value is - so your if statement should be more like

```
if (isset($_GET['enviar'])) {
```

If there is nothing in `$_GET['nombre']`, you will not see anything at all because the HTML is produced in the `else` part of that statement, and you only echo out the one value.

Answer (score 1):

This code will work for you

```
   <?php
    if (isset($_GET['enviar'])) { 
    //if ($_GET['enviar']) {

        echo $_GET['nombre'];
    } else {
        ?>
        <form action='#' method='get'>
            <p>
                Escribe tu nombre:  <input name='nombre'  type='text'  />
            </p>
            <p>
                <input name='enviar'  value='Enviar datos'  type='submit'  />
            </p>
        </form>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try below code : 

    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['enviar']) && $_GET['enviar']!="") {
    #  if (isset($_GET['enviar']) && $_GET['enviar'] == '1') { 
       echo $_GET['nombre'];
    } else {
    ?>
    <form action='get.php' method='get'>
        <p>
            Escribe tu nombre:  <input name='nombre'  type='text'  />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input name='enviar'  value='Enviar datos'  type='submit'  />´
        </p>
    </form>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, aquaranga; in the end of the polemic line = Why did you write code for a blank space; what's the meaning of " ! " ?

Comment: It is a not sign. $something !="" means $something should not be an empty string

Comment: Mplungjan = Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

When you do "$_GET['enviar'] == '1'" this means the value of field is supposed to be 1 but in here the value of this field is 'Enviar datos'.

Another you get notice : undefined index 'enviar' when you load form as the form field would not have been set before form post. So to remove this notice first you have to check if that form field has set or not.

```
if (isset($_GET['enviar']) && $_GET['enviar'] == 'Enviar datos') {
#  if (isset($_GET['enviar']) && $_GET['enviar'] == '1') { 
    echo '=='.$_GET['nombre'];
} else {
    ?>
    <form action='test.php' method='get'>
        <p>
            Escribe tu nombre:  <input name='nombre'  type='text'  />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input name='enviar'  value='Enviar datos'  type='submit'  />´
        </p>
    </form>
    <?php
}
```